# regex - Python exact match in lookahead assertion

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to retrieve the remaining of the sentence if the user-input variable *word* matches **exactly** of that found in string *a*.

```
a = 'hello there, I wanted to find out how to split this document'
word = 'wanted'
context = re.search(r'(?=^{user}$)(.*$)'.format(user=word), a)
context.group(0)
```

currently I have tried putting anchors and $ to ensure it matches exactly, but it would return this error message

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I'll get the same response when I changed the code below to:

```
a = 'hello there, I wanted to find out how to split this document'
word = 'wanted'
context = re.search(r'(?={user}$)(.*$)'.format(user=word), a)
context.group(0)
```

Any tips would be appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: Your current code assumes you need to get the whole string if it contains the whole word, `if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), s): print(s)`. If you need to split, use the corresponding method, `re.split(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), s)[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

**Without regex**:

```
a = 'hello there, I wanted to find out how to split this document'
word = 'wanted'

if word in a:
    print(a.split(word,1)[1])
```

**With regex** (using the [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)):

```
import re
if re.search(r'\b' + word + r'\b', a):
    # print('{0} found'.format(word))
    m = re.search("(?<=" + word + ")(.*)", a)
    print(m.group(0))
else:
    print('{0} not found'.format(word))
```

OUTPUT:

```
 to find out how to split this document
 to find out how to split this document
```